# Select and display calendar dates after 1 April,2016 irrespective of any table data. : MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select and list down calendar dates after 1 april'2016 irrespective of any table in database.
date should get added in result set as day changes.
can anyone please help me out ?

so far, I have tried this,

```
select date_format(DATE_sub(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 0 day),'%Y-%m-%d') as dat 
union
select date_format(DATE_sub(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 day),'%Y-%m-%d') as dat 
union
select date_format(DATE_sub(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 2 day),'%Y-%m-%d') as dat
```

But this is not practical, I know.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in SQL?

Comment: need to get a data from table for each day.
table date column may not have each day records.
It will return Null for the day from table where data is not there.
Will do the left join with dates we get with above query.

Comment: Swap the tables around, or do a right join instead